# If a woman converts to Judaism, is she niddah the first time she has sex

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, sexuality, niddah, yoreh-deah

The Halacha is that when a Jewish woman who is a virgin has sex for the first time, she becomes niddah whether or not there’s blood stains. If a woman converts to Judaism, and she had sex prior to conversion, would this Halacha apply to her as converts are likened to new people?

Comment: She only becomes a niddah because we assume there was a little blood and it was lost. By a convert that wouldn’t be applicable

Comment: Yeah. The blood is for someone who is losing their virginity. It wouldn't make sense here.

Comment: A concert is like a new born but that doesn't mean they are a new born. A woman who lost her virginity does not become a virgin